# Javascript loop through JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, json

Im trying to loop through a JSON object and gab the value `bingo`  m having trouble

```
{"testList":[{"number":"107832","secondList":[{"thirdList":[{"blah":"11111","blah2":"222222"}],"bingo":"0000"}]}]}
```

Its apart of 'secondList', Ijust dont know how to access without a nested loop.

```
for(var i=0;data.testList.length<1;i++){

    var fooObject = { 


            "number": data.testList[i].number,
            "bingo": <<<-----How to get this value???


    };
```

Comment: data.testList[i].secondList[0].bingo will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the arrays in this object are of length 1. If that will always be the case, then you don't have to loop through them:

```
fooObject = {
    "number" : data.testList[0].number,
    "bingo" : data.testList[0].secondList[0].bingo
};
```

If you have more than 1 item in the arrays and need to loop, you just need to loop through secondlist as well. Inside your for loop:

```
for (var j = 0; data.testList[i].secondList.length < 1; i++) {
    fooObject.bingo = data.testList[i].secondList[j].bingo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.testList[i].secondList[0].bingo` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need:

```
console.log( json.testList[0].secondList[0].bingo)
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/YA93Z/